# Using RDFa with an image inside of an H1 tag

Tags: seo, semantic-web, rdfa

I come from a development background but just recently starting learning SEO along with RDFa. I am working on our companies new website where the designer is using our different divisions logos at the top of their respective pages. There currently are not any H1 tags. I know I need to add and H1 but the way the pages were designed the logos are where I would usually put an H1 heading. And if I added an H1 with text it would throw off the design.

I also know that using images inside H1 isn't good practice even if I use the alt attribute.

So my question is if I put H1 tags around the image, then use RDFa will Google find this acceptable or will this be penalized. Here is my code example:

```
<div class="twelve columns" typeof="gr:BusinessEntity">
  <h1 property="gr:name" content="Thoughtwire Marketing">
     <img rel="foaf:depiction" src='http://www.thoughtwiremarketing.com/images/TW-marketing-logo.png' class='twmarketing' alt="Thoughtwire Marketing"/>
  </h1>
</div>
```

I defined my prefixes in the body tag and when I run my code through the validator at http://rdfa.info/play/ it seems like it would work, just not knowledgeable enough yet with SEO to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

(I adjusted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21141089/1591669) that I gave to your (now closed) question on SO.)

When a user-agent (including search engines) parses your RDFa, it doesn’t matter which element the RDFa is used on (except for special parsing rules). The user-agents learns something like the following:

> There is a business entity (`http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#BusinessEntity`) which has the name (`http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#name`) "Thoughtwire Marketing" (= literal value of the `content` attribute).

As you can see, it does not relate this statement to `div` or `h1`.

After this RDF is extracted, you could essentially imagine that the RDFa is "removed" from your page. So user-agents will see/interpret your plain markup, e.g.:

```
<div>
 <h1>
  <img src='http://www.thoughtwiremarketing.com/images/TW-marketing-logo.png' alt="Thoughtwire Marketing"/>
 </h1>
</div>
```

RDFa and HTML (semantics) are two different concepts.

I’m not sure that I understand your actual problem, but now you might have two questions:

- **Is my RDFa fine that way?** As you already linked to and tested your page with a RDFa parser/validator, probably yes, if the extracted RDF is what you want to say about your content.
- **Is my HTML fine that way?** From the HTML specification perspective, yes. And all consuming user-agents (including search engines) should be fine with it, too. Having images (especially logos) as content for headings is very common.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what unor said. The only thing I want to add is that you could use @property instead of @rel to align with [RDFa Lite](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/). So your snippet would like:

```
<div class="twelve columns" typeof="gr:BusinessEntity">
  <h1 property="gr:name" content="Thoughtwire Marketing">
     <img property="foaf:depiction" src='http://www.thoughtwiremarketing.com/images/TW-marketing-logo.png' class='twmarketing' alt="Thoughtwire Marketing"/>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Scor,
From what I have read and seen you have to use the rel attribute for foaf depictions.